# How do you check if self.crypto.randomUUID() is available in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, uuid

I'm building a React app and have a need to generate unique UUIDs. I am trying to use the function `randomUUID()` from `self.crypto`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID

If I don't want my code to explode if this runs in an unsupported browser, would this be sufficient?

```js
function GenerateGuid() {
    if (self && self.crypto) {
        console.log(self.crypto.randomUUID());
    }
    else {
        console.log("self.crypto not available");
    }
}

GenerateGuid();
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written? You can simplify it with optional chaining to `if (self.?crypto)`

Comment: Note that this won't work in object methods, since `self` will be the object, not the global object.

Comment: @Barmar just didn't know if that was enough or if I needed to be more specific with type checking (like "if self !== undefined") or similar

Comment: @Barmar the question focuses on "unsupported browsers" not on in code usage.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `randomUUID` to be available as `Crypto` is release since 2011 and `randomUUID` since 2021 (see [Crypto - Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto#browser_compatibility)). It is possible that you have a version without `randomUUID`. Check it via `typeof`. It returns `undefined` as a string and therefore fails. I dont see more things to test.

```js
function GenerateGuid() {
    if (self && self.crypto && typeof self.crypto.randomUUID === 'function') {
        console.log(self.crypto.randomUUID());
    }
    else {
        console.log("self.crypto not available");
    }
}

GenerateGuid();
```

Comment: I think this may be overkill. If `self.crypto` exists, it's reasonable to expect it to follow the specification.

Comment: That's not true: `Crypto` is an interface and `randomUUID` is a feature of this interface and therefore it is not said that `Crypto` contains `randomUUID` as libraries can release and change public features/functions/apis later on. In this case its actually the case. `Crypto` is release 2011 and `randomUUID` in 2021. See the compatibility list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I would use optional chaining to check whether `self.crypto.randomUUID` exists.

```js
function GenerateGuid() {
    if (self?.crypto?.randomUUID) {
        console.log(self.crypto.randomUUID());
    }
    else {
        console.log("self.crypto not available");
    }
}

GenerateGuid();
```